# Unable to install local cloud services

Tags: spring-batch, spring-tools-4

While I'm trying to install local cloud services using Spring Tool Suite 4

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.3.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201908130627
```

and I'm getting

> IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1
>   407 authenticationrequired" Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy
>   returns "HTTP/1.1 407 authenticationrequired" error messagge.

The same error occurs for if I try to edit Spring boot starters

https://start.spring.io

I've already configured my proxy server under Windows->Prefernces->General ->Network connections -> Active provider to Manual and configured our proxy details for HTTP and HTTPS schemas.

Note:
I'm able to install other plug-ins from eclipse market place.

Comment: Are you able to install local cloud services from CLI? (See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/)

Comment: I'm able to install it directly from spring site, but I'm not able to access spring.io site from STS. For example, if I try to edit Spring boot starters, I'm getting the exception in STS.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, j just add this parameter in file config STS.ini :

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```

You must restart Spring-STS after.